# In Oracle, what does [select * from table()] mean?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to search for information on this topic in sql but search is not showing me results.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(package/procedure/function);
```

Which topic does the above sql statement come under? Can I have a link to a doc?

Comment: Have you considered that it might be filed under "select"?  Have you considered just typing your exact question into Google?

Comment: To be fair *"table function"* is a pretty hard thing to google, because those are common terms with alternate meanings in SQL. But here is [a good primer on `table()` function](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/Oracle/PL-SQL/collection-types/return-table-from-function/index)

Comment: @APC My bad, I misread the question as "What does 'select * from <table>' mean", with <table> being a generic stand-in for any table. I'll leave my comment up to display my shame

Comment: @JoshEller - please delete it. Self-flagellation doesn't improve things. Internalising the lesson will ;-)

Answer (score 12):

The `TABLE` collection expression is described [here in the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#i2080063).

In short, it is used to convert a collection or pipelined function into a table that can be queried by a `SELECT` statement.

Typically, the collection must be of a datatype that is defined at the database level (i.e. a datatype that was created by a `create or replace type ...` statement).

e.g.

```
select *
from   table(sample_pkg.func_that_rtrns_array);
```